# Simple built-in way to encrypt and decrypt a file on a Mac via command-line?

Tags: mac, command-line, security, encryption

Are there any built in command-line tools that I can encrypt and decrypt a text file (and provide it some sort of password).

Comment: Built in = comes with the Mac, pre-installed?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

`openssl` comes pre-installed on Mac OS X.

You can use the following commands:

```shell
# encrypt file.txt to file.enc using 256-bit AES in CBC mode
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc

# the same, only the output is base64 encoded for, e.g., e-mail
openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in file.txt -out file.enc

# decrypt binary file.enc
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in file.enc -out file.txt

# decrypt base64-encoded version
openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -a -in file.enc -out file.txt
```

(copied from [OpenSSL Command-Line HOWTO: How do I simply encrypt a file?](http://www.madboa.com/geek/openssl/#how-do-i-simply-encrypt-a-file))

You will be prompted for a password. You can also specify a password on the command-line using `-pass pass:mySillyPassword` or `-pass file:/path/to/secret/password.txt`

These commands use 256-bit AES ecryption with Cipher Block Chaining (CBC), which is about as secure as it gets right now.

Comment: where do you enter your password?

Comment: Once you executed any of the above `openssl` commands, it asks you to `enter aes-256-cbc encryption password`.

Comment: @codecompleting Or specify `-pass pass:MYSECRETPASSWORD`, although the password is then of course not hidden from `ps`, etc.

Comment: If you use a salt, you will still be able to decrypt the file on a separate machine using only the password, correct?  (I understand that salts are to prevent rainbow tables, I just want to be sure I'm correct that the password is all that *I* would need to open the file on another box.)

Comment: @Wildcard Yes, the salt (actually, initialization vector) gets stored with the ciphertext in the encrypted file.

Comment: Question? Is this lossy in any way? I'm thinking of using this for important backup, so first I'll `zip -er` then run this on the zip

Comment: @KolobCanyon Encryption is never lossy. By definition, it requires being able to decrypt the ciphertext to restore the original plaintext. Just don't forget the key.

Comment: You commands work well with cygwin on a PC.

Comment: It should be noted that this is *not* secure if you manually type in your password. You should use key derivation.

Answer (score 9):

Mac OS X has the ability to create encrypted container files (similar to e.g. Truecrypt), that can optionally grow with the amount of data placed in them. Use *Disk Utility* to do this.

In *Disk Utility*, select *File » New » Blank Disk Image…* with one of the *sparse* image formats. Select AES-128 or AES-256 as encryption.

---

From the command line, the same functionality is available via the `hdiutil` program.

Comment: A bit overkill for a single text file intended for command line access, isn't it?  Can you open the file later via Linux et. al.?

Comment: @Wildcard Possibly (scope has a tendency to change); and no, but wasn't part of the question.

Comment: @DanielBeck, output bit identical as Ans1?

Answer (score 8):

I've built a shell script for that. You can use it on Mac or on Linux.

```
#!/bin/bash
#encrypt files with aes-256-cbc cipher using openssl

#encrypt files
if [ $1 == "-e" ];
then
    if [ -f "$2" ];
    then
    openssl aes-256-cbc -a -e -salt -in "$2" -out "$2.aes"
    else
       echo "This file does not exist!" 
    fi
#decrypt files
elif [ $1 == "-d" ];
then
    if [ -f "$2" ];
    then
        openssl aes-256-cbc -a -d -salt -in "$2" -out "$2.decrypt"
    else
        echo "This file does not exist!" 
    fi
#show help
elif [ $1 == "--help" ];
then
    echo "This software uses openssl for encrypting files with the aes-256-cbc cipher"
    echo "Usage for encrypting: ./encrypt -e [file]"
    echo "Usage for decrypting: ./encrypt -d [file]"
else
    echo "This action does not exist!"
    echo "Use ./encrypt --help to show help."
fi
```

Simply save this in a text file in issue chmod +x file to make it executable. 
after that use ./filename --help to get infos.

Comment: Needless use of `-a` will needlessly bloat the output file.