# Is Openssl Aes-Encryption Lossy?

Tags: macos, encryption, zip, openssl

As per [how to command-line aes-encrypt](https://superuser.com/a/370412/503444), am I able to use this as a reliable way to backup?

I'm on Os X btw.

What I've tried:

`zip -er ./test.zip ./test          # zip w/ password`

Added this to my `.bash_profile`

```
#$1 == input file
#$2 == output file
aesenc ()
{
        openssl enc -aes-256-cbc -salt -in "$1" -out "$2"
}

#$1 == enc file
#$2 == out file
aesdecr ()
{
        openssl enc -d -aes-256-cbc -in "$1" -out "$2"
}
```

`aesenc test.zip test.zip.enc`
`aesdecr test.zip.enc test.zip`

I checked the files and everything appears to be okay on the surface.

Just wanted to hear if anyone knew more?

Comment: Lossy encryption is a terrible idea. Are you confusing encryption with compression?

Answer (score 3):

I think you mean [lossy compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossy_compression) like a jpeg is, lossy compression irreversibly loses data, lossy compression would be terrible for data in general and only works for images because the image still looks "good enough" even after losing data.

Openssl's enc command is not "lossy"  so it *should* be reliable for data... but IMO using a program with a longer history & better key handling, like **gpg/pgp,** would be better for secure encrypted backups. It's recommend by Mr.Edward Snowden & is relatively "government proof," and at least in the past I've read some things about openssl's enc that are concerning.

See this question [OpenSSL vs GPG for encrypting off-site backups?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28247821/openssl-vs-gpg-for-encrypting-off-site-backups) for more info, like:

> from [this post on security.stackexchange.com](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29106/openssl-recover-key-and-iv-by-passphrase/29139#29139) (from Jan 2013) [and another](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31494/63902) by a 159K reputation user, the `openssl enc` command might leave something to be desired:
>
> > The encryption format used by OpenSSL is non-standard: it is "what OpenSSL does", and if all versions of OpenSSL tend to agree with each other, there is still no reference document which describes this format except OpenSSL source code. The header format is rather simple:
> >
> > magic value (8 bytes): the bytes 53 61 6c 74 65 64 5f 5f
> >        salt value (8 bytes)
> >
> > Hence a fixed 16-byte header, beginning with the ASCII encoding of the string "Salted__", followed by the salt itself. That's all ! No indication of the encryption algorithm; you are supposed to keep track of that yourself.
> >
> > The process by which the password and salt are turned into the key and IV is not documented, but a look at the source code shows that it calls the OpenSSL-specific [EVP_BytesToKey()](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/EVP_BytesToKey.html) function, which uses a custom [key derivation function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_derivation_function) with some repeated hashing. This is a non-standard and not-well vetted construct (!) which relies on the MD5 hash function of dubious reputation (!!); that function can be changed on the command-line with the *undocumented* `-md` flag (!!!); the "iteration count" is set by the `enc` command to **1** and cannot be changed (!!!!). This means that the first 16 bytes of the key will be equal to *MD5(password||salt)*, and that's it.
> >
> > **This is quite weak !** Anybody who knows how to write code on a PC can try to crack such a scheme and will be able to "try" several dozens of millions of potential passwords per second (hundreds of millions will be achievable with a GPU). **If you use "openssl enc", make sure your password has very high entropy !** (i.e. higher than usually recommended; aim for 80 bits, at least). Or, preferably, don't use it at all; instead, go for something more robust ([GnuPG](http://www.gnupg.org/), when doing symmetric encryption for a password, uses a stronger KDF with many iterations of the underlying hash function).
>
> `man enc` even has this under "BUGS":
>
> > There should be an option to allow an iteration count to be included.